# Auto Close Bootstrap-TimePicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap time picker, it works great but when I press tab between my fields the time picker remains open, so I have to click somewhere else to close it.

How can I make it close it self?
Using the time picker like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Starttid:</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        @Html.TextBox("startTime", Model.Times.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Sluttid:</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        @Html.TextBox("endTime", Model.Times.EndTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Rastlängd:</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        @Html.TextBox("breakTime", Model.Times.BreakTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
```

These are the settings for my timepicker:

```
    $.fn.timepicker.defaults = {
    defaultTime: 'current',
    disableFocus: false,
    disableMousewheel: true,
    isOpen: false,
    minuteStep: 15,
    modalBackdrop: true,
    orientation: { x: 'auto', y: 'auto'},
    secondStep: 15,
    showSeconds: false,
    showInputs: true,
    showMeridian: false,
    template: 'dropdown',
    appendWidgetTo: 'body',
    showWidgetOnAddonClick: true
  };
```

Comment: can u try `autoclose: true,`

Comment: @dreamweiver Tried that, dosen't seem to work, thanks though.

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/tc0camvc/ if you just click one of the fields and press the tab key you will notice the time picker won't close. And will hide the other pickers

Comment: @dreamweiver  autoclose is a boostrap **datepicker** option.   no such option for bootstrap timepicker

Answer (score 4):

You can use `'hideWidget'` method to close it when you loose focus from it and you can do the in conjunction with `blur` with event delegation:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.timepicker', function(){
   $(this).timepicker('hideWidget');
});
```

#### [Your updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tc0camvc/1/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick for me either, the time picker does not close when I tab to another field. Nor does it seem like that script is called. Only when the page loads though.  It's not inside a document ready function

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson: if you have found the solution, can you accept the answer

Comment: @dreamweiver i appreciate that.

Comment: @Jai Just noticed something... You can't change the hours if you try to change them the widget will close.

Comment: Seems to be back at round 1, that the field does not get closed if I tab.

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson oopss!!

Comment: @Jai I really appreciate the help

Comment: @JoakimCarlsson, looks like this shouldn't be marked as the answer anymore with the issues discussed here.

Comment: No good.  The very act of clicking on the widget is going to blur the input... and immediately close the widget...  :(

Answer (score 2):

Super-Janky(tm)  hack:

```
$("#precedingInput, #followingInput").on("focus", function(){
    $("timeInput").timepicker("hideWidget");
});
```

Comment: Hey, I'll take a Janky solution over no solution at all. At least this answer works.

Comment: been a while since this question was asked, but this is the only solution that fully worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `blur()` event in `jQuery`.  You just need a handle to that element, lets say its `id="xyz"`.

So you can make use of the `blur()` event as follows

```
$("#thedateinput").blur(function() {
  $(this).datepicker("hide");
});
```

Comment: So it would be something like this for my breaktime?     `$('#breakTime').blur(function() {
        $(this).datepicker("hide");
    });` If so it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: And doing that it also opens a DatePicker on the input field.

Comment: ... how do you click on the widget without bluring the input?

Answer (score 1):

having the same problem, I found another solution : listning for "Tab" keydown

```
$editor.keydown(e => {
    if (e.key == "Tab")
        $editor.timepicker('hideWidget');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple timepickers on my page (it's a time sheet application). My solution was to give each of my timepickers a class. Have an onchange event to run the calculations I needed on the value, and also an on keyup event that would close all timepickers, and open one on this timepicker.

```js
$('.timepicker').timepicker({

    // timepicker options here

}).on('change', function() {

    // calculations on the value here

}).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 9) {
        $('.timepicker').timepicker('hideWidget');
        $(this).timepicker('showWidget');
    }
});
```

Yes, I know that the it's a bit clunky, and that the code is no longer maintained, but sometimes we have to work with what we've got.